# PhpStorm keyboard multiple keystrokes

Tags: phpstorm, shortcut

Is it possible to create PhpStorm shortcut through double keystrokes? For example by pressing <kbd>f</kbd> character twice.

Comment: Take a look https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html#d1021685e323

Answer (score -2):

create every arbitrary shortcut is possible via [autoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/download/) . for  my case create a `comma.ahk` script with the code below:

```
:*:ff::
 send, {end},{enter}
Return
```

then run the script. that enough to make you free from going to end of line ,press the comma key and at last going to a new line!

Comment: PhpStorm supports multi-level shortcuts. See the link in a first comment to the actual question.

Comment: @LazyOne i think you misunderstood the question , Im not going to use key combination

Comment: voting down the answer is not  good while you dont provide any answer yourself. if anyone think phpstorm has this ability integrated with it , please put an explicit answer